# setting boolean values on void functions?

Tags: javascript

The following is my code:

```
$.win.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    $.txtAbout.blur();  
});
```

Event handler is called if someone clicks on the parent div/window, invoking the method. I would like to amend the code, so this happens:

```
$.win.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    $.txtAbout.blur();  
    //do something else if the above function is successfully called
    //code....
});
```

I am not sure what is the best way to do this? Is wrapping the above method call in another function then calling in the event handler with a boolean value the way to do it?

```
function test(){
    $.txtAbout.blur();   
    return true;
}

$.win.addEventListener('click', function(e) {   
    var check = test();
    if(check==true)
    {
    //do something else if the above function is successfully called
    //code....
    }
});
```

Comment: Depending on how you define "successfully called" it could be as simple as surrounding with a try/catch block

Comment: Your `test()` function always returns `true`, so what do you actually want to test?

Comment: I have a mobile textarea, when they click outside of the box into the main window. I am basically concerned if the person keeps clicking on the window/div, spamming it causing the api call to fail (which is responsible for sending data  i.e. the value in textabout to the server)